# Explicit call of Runnable.run

Tags: java, multithreading, interface

Somebody, who was working on my code before me, created some method and passed Runnable as parameter, more likely:

```
void myMethod(Runnable runnable){ runnable.run(); }
```

Then calling myMethod out of main looks like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ try 
{ myMethod(new Runnable(){ public void run() { //do something...; }}); } 
catch (Throwable t) { } }
```

So, to supply parameter to myMethod I need to instantiate object of (in this case anonymous) class implementing Runnable.

My question is: is it necessary to use Runnable in this example? Can I use any different interface? I mean I can create new interface with single method i.e.

```
interface MyInterface{ void doThis(); }
```

then change look of myMethod: `void myMethod(MyInterface myObject){ myObject.doThis(); }`

And of course client too:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
try { myMethod(new MyInterface (){ public void doThis() 
{ //do something...; }}); } 
catch (Throwable t) { } }
```

Or maybe something is about Runnable?!

Answer (score 5):

You could absolutely change the interface as you've suggested, but what is the point? What advantage does it bring to provide an instance of `MyInterface` rather than `Runnable`? One advantage of `Runnable` is that it would make it easier to make the code multi-threaded in the future, because most of the APIs that execute threads (e.g. [Executor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)) work with instances of `Runnable`.

Comment: The point is what about if I want to supply some parameter to myInterface in the future. I mean I cannot extend Runnable with overloaded run method. However, current implementation doesn't use threads, only calls runnable.run().

Comment: Could this change in the future?
I think not. In first moment I was not sure will calling run cause separate thread execution, but then I found some hints it wouldn't. That's why I want to avoid unnecessary calling runnable.run